# UIWebView and install questions

Tags: iphone

I have two questions which make me in trouble.

1. I drap a UIWebView on UIView,then I can't get the touch events,the one I can get is just from UIView.
2. Does iphone can run app just when it had installed? The other way,Can it launch itself at once when it finish installation.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with access to touch events?

Comment: I want make page translate animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q 1.
It because UIWebview eat touches, So touch does not get in UIView.
And if you need touch you need to subclass your application window with method,

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 //NSLog(@"tap detect");
 NSArray *allTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 UIView *touchView = [touch view];

 if (touchView && [touchView isDescendantOfView:<your webview>]) {
  //
  // touchesBegan
  //
 }
}
```

Q 2. I have no idea